# c# When NOT using WinForm memory clears VTK calculation/ When using WinForm it does not

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, vtk

I have "body of my code" that iteratively modifies then calculates statistics on a binary image file.

"body of my code" really works beautifully when I run the code in Console Application and even on WinForm Application if I run the code before the Winform shows up.  However, when I try to run the "body of my code" with button click of WinForm, I notice that memory increases until I get "Out of Memory" error.

The following is the code snippet

```
namespace vtkclasspractice
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //"Body of my code"    //works when it is here   
        }

        private void button_test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
               "Body of my code"  //memory piles-up until exception thrown
        }
     }
}
```

It seems as though the simple click button WinForm promotes the VTK classes in the "Body of my code" and prevents them from being garbage collected.  Also, it seems easily fixable, because I only have memory issue when I decide to use the click button.

Thank you,

Steve

Comment: Can you add the actual code that is called? It's likely to be something to do with life of the object that can be corrected by calling the dispose or using a 'Using' statement but until we see the code we won't be abel to help.

Comment: "Body of my code" is where the problem is. Just delete that line. :)

Comment: Thank you.  I will make the simplest possible version of "Body of my code" that exhibit the same symptom and post it up here.